# Cost associated with ADF Data Flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

What is the cost associated with Azure Data Factory Data Flow? Does the bill depend upon the data flows/Integration Runtimes we create? Also, does the bill depend on when we run a pipeline or starts billing from the time we create ADF Data Flow? If that's the case, is there an option to disable/pause ADF Data Flow Account in Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data Flows are visually-designed components inside of Data Factory that enable data transformations at scale. You pay for the Data Flow cluster execution and debugging time per vCore-hour. The minimum cluster size to run a Data Flow is 8 vCores. Execution and debugging charges are prorated by the minute and rounded up. Preview pricing discounts will continue until November 30, 2019.

[image]

Reference here: [Data Flow Execution and Debugging](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/data-pipeline/).

Azure also provide the examples to help you know more about the mapping data flow pricing, please reference:

1. [Using mapping data flow debug for a normal workday](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/pricing-concepts#using-mapping-data-flow-debug-for-a-normal-workday)
2. [Transform data in blob store with mapping data flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/pricing-concepts#transform-data-in-blob-store-with-mapping-data-flows)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! How about cost associated with Integration Runtimes?

Comment: Hi @user3693060, the  Data Flow Execution and Debugging document contains the integration runtimes.